# Passing multiple env files in docker run command

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables

I was just wondering how can i point to two env-files, say `/var/app/old/file.conf` and `/var/market/old/db.conf` , both in the command line as I find there is support for mutiple -e flags. Does Docker supports pointing to multiple env-file in a command line like the one below

```
docker run -d --hostname=158.64.72.80 -d -p 80:80 --env-file /var/app/old/file.conf --env-file /var/market/old/db.conf
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do exactly like the command you are running already. For example:

file1

```
GGG=/home/ppp
```

file2

```
HHH=/ter/ssd
```

Then run the Docker command:

```
docker run -it --env-file=/Users/user/file1 --env-file=/Users/users/file2 centos:6.6 /bin/bash
```

Then once in the container:

```
[user@99964c311fef ~]# env
HOSTNAME=99964c311fef
TERM=xterm
OLDPWD=/
 LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/user
GGG=/home/ppp   # <-- Here's file1
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/user
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
HHH=/ter/ssd   # <-- Here's file2
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/usr/bin/env
[user@99964c311fef ~]#
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, do you know how to select value from same env file(.env01 & .env02) if key is same?